# Checking for duplicates per column in a dynamic Excel array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, duplicates, formula

I'm trying to generate a formula in Excel that evaluates the presence of duplicates in a dynamic array per column and then returns a new 1-dimensional array that contains either True or False when duplicates are present/absent. See the simplified example below.

Example array:

```
{a,b,c,d;
 d,e,f,g;
 a,h,i,j}
```

The output of the formula should result in `{True,False,False,False}`. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly simple, agreed, though until Microsoft release functions such as `BYCOL` it's anything but, assuming you're wanting to obtain your array output using a single formula.

One option would be:

`=LET(ρ,A1:D3,κ,ROWS(ρ),ε,COLUMNS(ρ),η,SEQUENCE(κ*ε,,0),γ,MATCH(ρ,INDEX(ρ,1+MOD(η,κ),1+QUOTIENT(η,κ)),0)+SEQUENCE(,ε)/10^6,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,κ),N(INDEX(FREQUENCY(γ,γ)=0,SEQUENCE(κ,ε))))>0)`

Replace `A1:D3` as required.

Hopefully someone will come along with an improvement.

Comment: Thanks you so much, this works!

Comment: Glad to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd have `BYCOL()` you can use something like:

```
=BYCOL({a,b,c,d;d,e,f,g;a,h,i,j},LAMBDA(x,COUNTA(UNIQUE(x))<>ROWS(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly dynamic as CHOOSE can't be set that way but if you have a smaller number of columns you can use the following:

```
=LET(data,E4:H6,CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(1,4),
IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,1)))=ROWS(data),FALSE,TRUE),
IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,2)))=ROWS(data),FALSE,TRUE),
IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,3)))=ROWS(data),FALSE,TRUE),
IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,4)))=ROWS(data),FALSE,TRUE))
)
```